# Getting an error while trying to get to an API data to pandas with JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

So I'm trying to put the data from an API to a pandas dataframe, but by using the following code, I'm running with the following error:

````
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BBAR?p=BBAR&.tsrc=fin-srch'
data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
data```

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
````

Comment: that's a webpage you're trying to parse, not json

Comment: Are you sure the server sends you Json data and not HTML page?

Comment: Well now I feel like an idiot, I'll try with JSON data this time, thanks!